# Cannot install Visual Studio Express without adding SQL Server Express

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would like to install Visual Studio Express, but Microsoft insist you get it using a tool called 'WebPI', which then tells me I have to download SQL Server 2008 R2 **Express** as well.
http://www.microsoft.com/express/Web/

Since I already have the **full** version of SQL 2008 R2 installed, I would rather not! So how can I get past this WebPI annoyance? It won't let me opt out of the SQL install, and it asks me to set a "sa" password before I can carry on! I don't want it to overwrite my current SQL install.

You can avoid WebPI and download a .ISO file from here...
http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/E/5/1E5F1C0A-0D5B-426A-A603-1798B951DDAE/VS2010Express1.iso
...but that is a 600Mb file so I assume it includes SQL too.

Comment: Microsoft still haven't realised this is a problem in 2015, as I'm installing Visual Web Developer on another machine now. SIGH. I will try go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9709959 which should give me VWD only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I spotted an .EXE link on a random forum...
http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/D/6/0D600544-AD1A-45FB-8D40-838EBF3C03EC/vwd_web.exe
...only 3Mb so looks about right....but then it still says it wants to install SQL R2 Management Objects and then fires off a 124Mb download!

Eventually this seems to have worked, and hasnt killed my existing SQL R2 install.

Answer (score -1):

wouldn't it be better to uninstall SQL 2008 R2 and then install visual studio

Comment: Then I would lose all my existing databases and end up with a 'lower' version of SQL!

Answer (score -1):

Once you click on the install button it shows you the download links to all of the individual files it will download and install, you can then click on them individually leaving out the files you don't want.

At least I hope that's the case, I'm just trying that now.